# Python Splitting strings into even and odd two dataframes efficiently

Tags: python, sorting, split, pandas

I am splitting dataframe into even and odds and sorted in numeric order based on a field as seen below:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['AA', 'SL', 'BB', 'D0', 'Dk', 'FF'],
                    'ID' : ['100', '15', '20', '25', '37', '32'],
                    'Trans' : ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'N', 'N']}).set_index('Type')

Even=df[df['ID'].astype(float)%2==0].sort(['ID'],ascending=[False])
Odd=df[df['ID'].astype(float)%2==1].sort(['ID'],ascending=[False])

print Even
print Odd

       ID Trans
Type           
FF     32     N
BB     20     C
AA    100     C

[3 rows x 2 columns]
      ID Trans
Type          
Dk    37     N
D0    25     C
SL    15     C

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

But lets say in the 'ID' Column I have some strings that can't be interpreted as floats such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['AA', 'SL', 'BB', 'D0', 'Dk', 'FF'],
                    'ID' : ['100', '15A', '20 D', '25XXX', '37', '32'],
                    'Trans' : ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'N', 'N']}).set_index('Type')
```

and I want to the output to be:

```
       ID Trans
Type           
FF     32     N
BB     20 D   C
AA    100     C

[3 rows x 2 columns]
      ID Trans
Type          
Dk    37     N
D0    25XXX  C
SL    15A    C

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?  something like using df.str.split('FLOATVALUE'[-1]) and then merge the data again by ID? I know Regex can be used but it would be slow.

Answer (score 4):

For best performance, an easy improvement is doing the even/odd determination only once. (Above you do it twice.)

```
is_even = df['ID'].astype(int) % 2 == 0

even = df[is_even]
odd = df[~is_even]
```

If your IDs are variable-length numbers followed by variable-length strings, I'm not sure how you can get around something like regex. But pandas' vectorized string methods are pretty fast. Have you tried them?

In the current development version (to be released as version 0.13 any day now) you can use `str.extract`:

```
is_even = df['ID'].str.extract('(\d+).*').astype(int) % 2 == 0
```

In previous versions, look at `str.match`.

Comment: Great! I am actually using a December version of pandas 0.13 development version! Just to be clear what you did was use [StringMethods.extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html?highlight=extract) Then entered a Regex for digits? to extract the numbers.

Comment: any good ways of appending the string at the end for the output? (ie. for 25XXX the XXX entry should be appended back) Or should the string just be extracted and concatenated later on?

Comment: Re: your first comment, yes. Re: your second comment, it seems like you could hang onto the original ID column -- why discard it if you're just going to append the numbers back? If that doesn't answer your question, open a separate question showing your desired output.